# Django-rest-framework fetch foreign key field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

serializers.py

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = "__all__"
```

models.py

```
class Employee(CreateUpdateModel):
    emp_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, validators =[validate_min_5])
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, validators =[validate_min_3])
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, validators =[validate_min_2])

class Password(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="employee_password")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, validators =[validate_min_5])
```

When i am visiting /employee/ i am not getting `password` field i want all fields of employee along with password also.

Please have a look.

Comment: Exactly why do you store the password in a separate model? Furthermore if you do not need the password to call a service, you should *hash* the password.

Comment: It was there only in the model. I don't wants to change model of working version of app